# Retrieving information in Powershell from Az Devops result

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am retrieving group informations from Azure Devops via the azure CLI (`az devops security group membership list --id "xxx"`). Unfortunately, the result is somehow not usable in Powershell.

This is the result json, I need the mailAddress.

```
{
  "DESCRIPTOR": {
    "descriptor": "DESCRIPTOR",
    "directoryAlias": "DIRECTORYALIAS",
    "displayName": "DISPLAYNAME",
    "domain": "DOMAIN",
    "legacyDescriptor": LEGACYDESCRIPTOR,
    "mailAddress": "MAILADDRESS",
    "metaType": "METATYPE",
    "origin": "ORIGIN",
    "originId": "ORIGINID",
    "principalName": "PRINCIPALNAME",
    "subjectKind": "SUBJECTKIND",
    "url": "URL"
  },
.....
}
```

Has someone worked with the results and knows how to get the mailAddress?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) Cmdlet to convert a JSON-formatted string to a custom object or a hash table.

Comment: Yes I know this Cmdlet, but still the result is not usable.

Comment: @Mens Updated my answer to address your requirement to extract multiple addresses. Please check. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** You should be able to get to the `mailAddress` property with `$result.'DESCRIPTOR'.mailAddress`.

Here is the why and how:

```
PS C:\> $result = az devops security group membership list --id "xxx" --organization "yyy" | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\> $result.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

PS C:\Users\BHANNADE> $result | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                                                 MemberType   Definition
----                                                 ----------   ----------
Equals                                               Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode                                          Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType                                              Method       type GetType()
ToString                                             Method       string ToString()
aad.NmEzOTc1MTIt...xYr58NWZkLTg4MDQtY2QxZGUxODkzMWQ4 NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject ...
aad.Y2I1NjM2NjIt...mZi03NzA5LTg4MWQtNDZjZmI5NjRjYWMy NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject ...
```

This tells us that `$result` is a PowerShell Custom Object with the descriptors themselves as Members (NoteProperties).

Therefore, `$result.'DESCRIPTOR'.mailAddress` should let you get to the `mailAddress` property:

```
PS C:\> $result.'aad.NmEzOTc1MTIt...xYr58NWZkLTg4MDQtY2QxZGUxODkzMWQ4'.mailAddress
abc.xyz@email.com
```

**UPDATE:**

There may be multiple members in a Team and so your `$result` may contain multiple objects. You can extract all the email addresses as follows:

```
$properties = $result | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$mailAddresses = @()
$mailAddresses += $properties.ForEach({$result.$_.mailAddress})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use Azure CLI with [Global Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/security/group/membership?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_devops_security_group_membership_list) `--query` and you can  get the mailAddress like this:

```
az devops security group membership list --id "xxx" --query "DESCRIPTOR.mailAddress"
```

Also, you can change the Output format with `--output`.

Answer (score 0):

This command returns JSON by default.

You can convert from JSON to a PSCustomObject via `ConvertFrom-Json`

The next issue is that this command doesn't return a collection as you'd expect, but returns one object with properties (each property name being the descriptor value, as you saw).

As others have suggested you can get those properties names via `Get-Member -PropertyType NoteProperty`...  Or you can access these properties via the object's `PSObject` property.  The advantage of the latter is that you can then access the property's `value` property - which is what you're after

```
# fetch the direct members of our group (NOTE: this is not recursive :/)
$secGroupInfo = az devops security group membership list --org $orgUri --id $someId | 
    ConvertFrom-Json

# list all mails in this group
$secGroupInfo.PSObject.Properties.where{$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'}.Value.mailAddress

# or display mails & related info in a table
$secGroupInfo.PSObject.Properties.where{$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'}.Value | 
    ft displayName, principalName, originId, mailAddress -AutoSize
```